# Delete values in Constant.h file ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables

How to delete a constant value defined in Constant.h file in iOS?

**CODE**

in **Constant.h** File i defined the constant as
`#define SELECTED_FINANCIAL_INSTITUTIONS @"selectedFinancialInstitutions"`

And in Success of a service i stored the value like

```
[SharedManager sharedManager].dashboardInput = @{SELECTED_FINANCIAL_INSTITUTIONS:self.originalDataArray};
```

**PROBLEM**

When the Service gets called for the second time the `SELECTED_FINANCIAL_INSTITUTIONS` value gets updated with the current institution value along with the old value. But i need only the current institution name.

`self.selectedFinancialInstitutions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dashboardSettings[SELECTED_FINANCIAL_INSTITUTIONS] copy]];`

`self.selectedFinancialInstitutions` Array has previous selected values. But i need only new values in this array

So Can anybody tell how to delete the values available in constant before assigning new value into it.

Comment: Please show some code of Constant.h

Comment: Delete the line from the file.

Comment: @user1000 I updated the question

Comment: In my opinion this is not the objective of a constant file , you should not change this value in your code, that is why you are using the name Constant for this file,

Comment: Yup... I'm using that value throughout my project until one particular service gets called. On success of that service i need to update the constant with new value. In my case the value is updated along with the old value. @user1000

Answer (score 1):

If `self.originalDataArray` is mutable array, then remove all its existing elements before calling the api.

```
[self.originalDataArray removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: `self.originalDataArray` is the response array and that array gets initialized on the service call. But the issue is with `SELECTED_FINANCIAL_INSTITUTIONS` which has new and previous values. @Lal Krishna

Comment: how you store values to this array : `dashboardSettings[SELECTED_FINANCIAL_INSTITUTIONS]`

Answer (score 0):

Call it before adding new data

```
[[SharedManager sharedManager].dashboardInput removeObjectForKey: SELECTED_FINANCIAL_INSTITUTIONS];
```